# Manage multiple form inputs and it's value via React state

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

Let me start with an example so you guys can know what is the issue and what I want to achieve.

In my project I'll have multiple user form on the same page and number of forms will be dynamic (depends on user number if there are 3 users then 3 forms, if 10 users then 10 forms etc).

Let's assume all forms will have 3 fields (keep it simple here) like **firstName** , **middleName** , **lastName**.

Now let assume we have 3 users so 3 inputs will appear on the page.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="middleName" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" />
</form>
```

We have 3 users this time so above form will appear 3 times. Here actually what I have taken only one form for all 3 users. What I have done is shown below.

```
<form>
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="middleName" value="" />
   <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" />
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```

When user submits the form I want an array of value for each form field.

What and How result I want is below.

**['tome hanks' , 'shahrukh khan', 'john']** // firstname of all 3 users

**['tome hanks' , 'shahrukh khan', 'john']** // middlename of all 3 users

**['tome hanks' , 'shahrukh khan', 'john']** // lastname of all 3 users

I have tried [this tutorial](https://goshakkk.name/array-form-inputs/) but not exactly what I need.

Maybe I can achieve this using React state but don't know how?

If Redux is helpful than it's fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { firstName: 'John1', middleName: 'Daniel1', lastName: 'Paul1' },
        { firstName: 'John2', middleName: 'Daniel2', lastName: 'Paul2' },
        { firstName: 'John3', middleName: 'Daniel3', lastName: 'Paul3' },
        { firstName: 'John4', middleName: 'Daniel4', lastName: 'Paul4' },
      ],
    };
  }

  _onChangeUser = (index, field, event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state => {
      const users = [
        ...state.users.slice(0, index),
        {
          ...state.users[index],
          [field]: newValue,
        },
        ...state.users.slice(index + 1),
      ];
      return {
        users,
      };
    });
  };

  _onSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do something with this.state.users.
    console.log(this.state.users);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this._onSubmit}>
          {this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                value={user.firstName}
                onChange={this._onChangeUser.bind(this, index, 'firstName')}
              />
              <input
                value={user.middleName}
                onChange={this._onChangeUser.bind(this, index, 'middleName')}
              />
              <input
                value={user.lastName}
                onChange={this._onChangeUser.bind(this, index, 'lastName')}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"><div>
```

Comment: let me try your answer.

Comment: for users state you have taken 4 users static but I want dynamic user state how can I do that ? this.state = {users : ['firstname': " " , "middlename": " ", "lastname" : " "]} will work ?

Comment: sometimes I have 2 users , 5 users , 10 users, 20 users for that how to set users state ?

Comment: Yes 4 is just an example, there's no hardcoding so just change the initial array values and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Declare your state variable as an array. Below should fulfill your requirement.

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
         firstNameArray:[],
         middleNameArray:[],
         lastNameArray:[],
         fName:” “,
         mName:””,
         lName:””
    }

   this.changeFirstName = this.changeFirstName.bind(this);
   this.changeMiddleName=             this.changeMiddleName.bind(this);
   this.changeLastName=this.changeLastName.bind(this);
   }

   changeFirstName(event){
   this.setState({
          firstNameArray:event.target.value,
          fName: event.target.value
   })

   changeMiddleName(event){
   this.setState({
   middleNameArray: event.target.value,
   mName: event.target.value
   })
  }

  changeLastName(event){
  this.setState({
   lastNameArray: event.target.value,
   lName: event.target.value
   })
```

Call each function on your input field like below

```
    <input type=‘text’ name=‘fName’ value=    {this.state.fName} onChange={this.changeFirstName} />
```

Do it in the same way for other two input fields as well. Hope this answers your question.